# How to extract the weblinks?

Tags: search

I need to get weblinks from a buffer (http....) and put them into scratch buffer. This code partially works, but the weblinks are
inserted in the same buffer.

I'm new at programming.

```
(defun get-weblinks ()
  "Get weblinks from a buffer"
  (interactive)
  (let (p1 p2 url)
    (while (search-forward "http")
      (backward-char 4)
      (setq p1 (point))
      (search-forward "jpg")
      (setq p2 (point))
      (setq url (buffer-substring p1 p2))
      (insert url "\n")
      )))
```

How can I finish the function?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The solution will likely entail either `re-search-forward` or `re-search-backward` with an appropriate regex that matches the entire link; and then use `(match-beginning 0)` and `(match-end 0)` to get the points for the beginning and ending of the link -- assuming the regex matches everything.  You can use `M-x re-builder` to come up with a complete regexp; or you can Google for it and then check with `re-builder` to see if it matches them all.  I saw several examples in my brief Google searches dealing with the generalized type of links with `href` or `src`, so you'll need to do some hunting.

Comment: You can `push` the results into a list and then regurgitate the list when your all done -- e.g., `(let (result my-list) ... *while* search stuff (setq result "thelink") (push result my-list) ... move to wherever or whatever buffer ... (mapc (lambda (x) (insert x "\n")) my-list))`

Comment: This is the improved function. It is ok for now. The weblinks are printed line by line in message buffer.

    (defun get-weblinks ()
      (interactive)
      (let (p1 p2 url)
        (while (re-search-forward "http.+jpg" nil t)
           (setq p1 (match-beginning 0))
            (setq p2 (match-end 0))
            (message (buffer-substring p1 p2) "\n")
             )))

This is very useful to me. 

Thank you. @lawlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```lisp
(defun get-weblinks ()
"Goto the beginning of the current buffer; perform the search and store the links;
go back to the point of origin; create a new buffer; iterate over the list and insert
the links into the new buffer; switch to the new buffer; go to the beginning of the
new buffer."
(interactive)
  (let (url-list)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward "http.+jpg" nil t)
        (push
          (buffer-substring-no-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
          url-list)))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "*URL*")
      (mapc
        (lambda (url)
          (insert url "\n"))
        url-list))
    (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer "*URL*"))
    (goto-char (point-min))))
```

Comment: wow..
It works perfect, it is a very useful function to me.
I'm motivated to learn more emacs. I will analyze your code to understand step by step.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Nice, always something to learn from @lawlist code, thank you.